# Как склонировать данный репозиторий под ms/windows?

Tags: eclipse, cmd, mercurial, репозиторий

У меня установлена *Java* платформа, и *Eclipse*.
Установил *Mercurial*. Теперь ввожу в *cmd* команду

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/skolos/lispdev
```

Результат:

> "hg" не является внутренней или внешней
>   командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

---

вот что получилось после клонирования:

[image: вот что получилось]

Answer (score 3):

HG - это клиент Mercurial.

Скачайте и установите [Mercurial SCM](https://mercurial.selenic.com/). Он пропишется у вас в PATH, и clone заработает.

Если скачали именно его - то просто проверьте PATH - и добавьте туда путь к HG. И перезапустите cmd.

Comment: спасибо, движение есть!

Answer (score 2):

у *eclipse* есть [*plugin*](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mercurialeclipse) для работы с *mercurial*-репозиториями.

вот [инструкция на английском](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/First_steps.wiki#!introduction-to-mercurialeclipse) по клонированию репозитория с *bitbucket-а* с помощью этого *plugin-а*.

для клонирования

- выбираете: *File->Import...*
- в диалоге импорта: *Mercurial->Clone repository using MercurialEclipse*
- в диалоге клонирования вставляете в поле **url** адрес нужного вам репозитория: `https://bitbucket.org/skolos/lispdev`
- нажимаете *finish*.

Comment: Блин, у меня help в Eclips не так выглядит как у них в инструкции. Нету там никакого Marketplace Client. Качаю новый Eclips.

Comment: добавил в ответ ссылку на клонирование репозитория с *bitbucket-а*

Comment: Установил новый Eclips, там есть этот магазин Marketplace Client. Теперь нужно что-то выбрать, и установить, но что именно?

Comment: на [странице](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mercurialeclipse) по центру есть кнопка *install*. её можно «перетащить» на окно *eclipse*.

Comment: вроде получилось, перезагрузился Eclips. Уже кидать клон в cmd? Опять ничего.

Comment: вторая строка в моём ответе содержит ссылку на инструкцию по клонированию.

Comment: а как тут фотку добавить, чтобы показать что получилось? Наустанавливалось куча пакетов. Но это ещё не конец.

Comment: нажимаете [edit], добавляете фотографию (есть кнопка «изображение» в панели инструментов).

Comment: добавил, жду экспертную проверку.

Comment: Остановился на Commit: Commit your changes to your local repository. Не вижу его меню Eclips.

Comment: хм. прошу прощения, что сбил вас с толку по поводу кнопке [edit] — я забыл, что мы пишем комментарии к моему ответу, а не к вашему вопросу. я уже вставил картинку в вопрос.

Comment: не надо ничего коммитить. по ссылке есть подробная [инструкция](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/First_steps.wiki#!introduction-to-mercurialeclipse). что именно вам в ней непонятно?

Comment: Я нажал import, и  добавил URL там в поле. Результат на картинке. У меня SBCL установлен. Я проверил меню Preferences, на наличие Lisp. Но его там нет.

Comment: кажется теперь надо сделать 4-й пункт вот этой инструкции https://bitbucket.org/skolos/lispdev/wiki/Developer%20notes

Comment: 1. я перевёл инструкцию по ссылке. 2. вы не устанавливаете  *lisp*, вы сейчас копируете к себе исходники плагина `lispdev`.

Comment: *кажется теперь надо сделать* — для скачивания исходников плагина??? кажется, вы чего-то не понимаете. «склонировать репозиторий» — это сделать «клон» репозитория (с исходным кодом). по-простому — скопировать к себе все файлы репозитория и историю их изменений.

Comment: так вам удалось получить исходники этого плагина?

Comment: та вроде удалось

Comment: значит всё, вопрос решён. если у вас есть другие вопросы — создавайте «новый вопрос». таков формат этого сайта: вопрос-ответ.

Comment: я сейчас смотрю run configuration, могу ещё фотку приложить. Ясно, создам новую тему.

Comment: вопрос-ответ. таков формат общения на этом сайте

Comment: совершите, пожалуйста, двухминутный ознакомительный [tour]

Comment: хорошо, ознакомлюсь. Вот новая тема: [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434819/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-eclipse)